# Is there a simple proof that the homomorphism $\phi:SU(2)\rightarrow SO(3)$ is surjective?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am wondering, is there a simple, direct proof that the double cover
$$\phi:SU(2)\rightarrow SO(3)$$
is a surjective map? Explicitly, if we identify $\mathbb R^3$ with $\text{im }\mathbb H$, and then this space with a subspace of $2\times 2$ complex matrices, then we can define $\phi$ as
$$A\mapsto(X\mapsto AXA^+)$$
however, it seems to me that it is really complicated to see directly that this map is surjective. The only way I see one can prove this is surjective is via studying the associated lie algebra map
$$\phi^*:\mathfrak{su}(2)\rightarrow\mathfrak{so}(3)$$
which, after some tedious computation, one can check is an isomorphism. Then, one knows that the exponential map of a connected compact Lie group, like $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$, is surjective. This fact, however, is aconsequence of the existence of maximal tori, etc., which is a highly nontrivial fact. That $\phi^*$ is an isomorphism toghether with the surjectivity of the exponential maps implies the surjectivity of $\phi$.

My question is, can we conclude directly the surjectivity of $\phi$ via a simpler argument?

Comment: You don't really need surjectivity of the exponential map for this argument. The inverse function theorem shows that $\phi$ is a bijection between neighborhoods of the identity. It follows that the image is an open subgroup, but $SO(3)$ is connected so it's everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just directly verify it.

To that end, I prefer to use the isomorphism $SU(2)\cong Sp(1)$  [see this MSE question and answer).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264730/isomorphism-between-su2-and-u1-mathbb-h)

In this language, a unit quaternion $q$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^3\cong \operatorname{Im}\mathbb{H}$ by conjugation:  $q$ corresponds to the linear map $C_q:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $C_q(v) = qvq^{-1} = qv\overline{q}$.

A general element $B\in SO(3)$ is given geometrically by specifying a fixed axis and an angle of rotation about that axis.  So, to show the map $Sp(1)\rightarrow SO(3)$ is surjective, it suffices to show we can get any axis of rotation and any angle of rotation using a function as above.

So, suppose the axis is specified by a point $v = (v_1,v_2,v_3)\in S^2\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, and the angle is given by some $\theta \in [0,\pi]$.

Consider the unit quaternion $q:= \cos(\theta/2) + \sin(\theta/2)v$.  Then $q\in Sp(1)$ and $C_q(v) = qvq^{-1} = v$ since real numbers and $v$ commute with themselves.

Moreover, if a unit vector $w$ is perpendicular to $v$, then \begin{align*} C_q(w) &= (\cos(\theta/2) + \sin(\theta/2)v)w(\cos(\theta/2)-\sin(\theta/2)v)\\ &=  \cos^2(\theta/2) w +\cos(\theta/2)\sin(\theta/2)(vw - wv) -\sin^2(\theta/2) vwv.\end{align*}

Now, because $v$ and $w$ are perpendicular and purely imaginary, $wv = -vw$.  (See, e.g., [this MSE question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865094/need-help-determining-the-pairs-of-quaternions-that-anticommute/1034538))  Moreover, this implies that $vwv = -v^2 w = w$.  Here, $v^2 = vv = -v \overline{v} = -|v|^2 = -1$, which is true for any purely imaginary unit length quaterion.)

Thus, $C_q(w) = (\cos^2(\theta/2) - \sin^2(\theta/2)) w + 2\cos(\theta/2)\sin(\theta/2)(vw) = \cos(\theta)w + \sin(\theta)(vw).$

Finally, simply notice that $vw$ is perpendicular to both $v$ and $w$.  Indeed, $1\bot w$ and multiplication by $v$ is an isometry, so $v\bot vw$ and likewise, $1\bot v$ and multiplication by $w$ is an isometry, so $w\bot vw$.

Thus, we identify the formula for $C_q(w)$ as rotation of by angle $\theta$ in the plane perpendicular to $v$, so we are done.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was waiting for.